# When I call my display function my page never refreshes

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to create a program that takes XML information and then displaces a user interface. The interface is supposed to have buttons that will return the user to the home page or back to the previous page (if they are not on the home page). The page is also supposed to have a button that will run the display function that i believe is written properly to display the program as written so far. However, when I run the program and click the button nothing happens. I have tried running the program in debug mode and have verified that the XML did parse correctly and that the program recognizes that the button was pushed and the page was supposed to change. Here is the display function as written:

```
public void display(String pageShortName){
    this.setTitle(projectTitle + ": " );//sets the window title to project title plus window name
    currentPageShortName = pageShortName;
    this.getContentPane();
    JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();//create a new panel
    JPanel childButtonBar = new JPanel();
    toolBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.WIDTH, 100));//set the prefered size to the width of the screen and 100 tall
    childButtonBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.WIDTH, 200));

    toolBar.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    toolBar.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    childButtonBar.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    childButtonBar.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    if(c.linkIdList.get(pageShortName).hasHomeButton()){//if the page has a home button
        toolBar.add(new ChildButton("Home", c.linkIdList.get("home").getShortName(), this));//add a home button to the tool bar
    }
    if(c.linkIdList.get(pageShortName).hasBackButton()){//if the page has a back button
        toolBar.add(new ChildButton("Back", previousPageShortName, this));//add a back button to the page
    }
    if(c.linkIdList.get(pageShortName).hasChildButtons()){
        for(int i = 0; i<c.linkIdList.get(pageShortName).getButtonList().size(); i+=1){
            XMLButton currentXMLButton = c.linkIdList.get(pageShortName).getButtonList().get(i);
            childButtonBar.add(new ChildButton(currentXMLButton.name, currentXMLButton.linkShortName, this));
        }
    }

    this.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);//add the tool bar to the top of the screen
    this.add(childButtonBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    this.revalidate();//first step of redraw
    this.repaint();//second step of redraw
}
```

And here is the action listener function for the button when it is pushed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     userInt.previousPageShortName = userInt.currentPageShortName;
     userInt.display(linkShortName);
 }
```

Can anyone help me find why it wont update when the button is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

To update a JFrame or JComponent

```
this.validate();
```

needs to be called